# Answer or ignore narrow situation questions where an answer was still marked accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895291/access-2010-sql-update-query) which now has been closed with the "off topic" reason. I don't think the description of the close reason was accurate at all.

The reason for the error was instantly obvious to me, and my answer was eventually accepted.

Stack Overflow wants to be a repository of good answers, but I'd say the odds that anyone would ever search for this question are slim.

I then did a search for something still open and on topic and found: [Bang Notation and Dot Notation in VBA and MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923957/bang-notation-and-dot-notation-in-vba-and-ms-access). From my own experience with Access programmers this is a question oft-asked.

What's the consensus on questions that are obviously one-off situations?  Answer them?  Answer them and then vote to close?  Ignore them?  How do people generally deal with these types of questions?

Comment: Thanks for giving him the answer, I'm sure it helped his day.

Answer (score 7):

> I understood the problem and gave an answer to it, the reason the OP was getting an error was instantly obvious to me, and the OP did go back and give me the checkmark.

So the question you now have to ask yourself is, what purpose would be served by reopening the question, given that it has apparently run its course?

The close reason given is entirely appropriate *to the question that was asked.*  The answers that a question receives has no bearing on whether or not the question itself should be closed.

Comment: I don't think that was the best reason, since he had provided code and at least stated the error (though it would certainly have been better if he had posted the exact error).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the comments do explain why it was closed.  You should expect the close reason to be generic (there are only a handful of categories); in this case, more specifics were provided in the comments.  If the author wants to see it re-opened, it wouldn't hurt for them to start by editing their question to address all issues raised in the comments, at a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

The two questions aren't parallel.

Your first example, which you answered, is a pretty generic, *"I have an error, which I can't be bothered to tell you"* question. There's probably a few thousand other questions that exist because of exactly the same error and if the OP had Googled that error they'd have found one. If they'd bothered to attempt to apply the solution to their own question then they'd never have needed to ask the question.

I'm guessing here, because the OP doesn't state any of this, just posts something and complains about an error.

Given that [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and all it's variants (I searched for `[*sql*][oracle]`, there'll be more) has 499k questions, slightly more than PHP and putting it in 4<sup>th</sup> place overall, this tag gets *a lot* of crap. A significant proportion of it as described. I'll be happy if we closed 10% of it.

It's worth noting for all you others out there that occasionally questions will survive, without showing the slightest effort. This is because people look at it and say *"OoOoh, that's an interesting problem"*. These are a lot rarer than *"I have duplicates"* or *"I have an error"*, but it's worth noting that people don't always enforce the close reasons equally.

Your second question is about two different operators and whether they are equivalent. Yes, it may have been Googlable at the time, but you're forgetting something. Stack Overflow's goal is to become a repository of programming knowledge. 3 years ago there was quite a lot to add, and the amount of effort you needed to show was lower. This isn't a reason to penalise a question for doing exactly what they were meant to. And, not that I think the question can show "effort" in this instance, it would be a pointless, meaningless addition that would only serve to annoy.

I don't believe the second question is a one-off situation, but it still fits in to my answer. If you come across a one-off situation, ask yourself two questions:

1. Has it been asked before?
2. Has the OP bothered to do anything? That's including being so nice as to add the error so that it's in the search in the future and other's can find it and not ask the inevitable duplicate questions.

For 1, obviously close as a duplicate. For 2, pick and choose the most appropriate reason.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here is editing. Make the question more google-able. As the first question stands now, you helped one person with one problem because your knowledge of the domain is extensive enough to be able to **read between the lines** of the question.

You could make the question more applicable to other people, if you're inclined to do so, by editing in that missing information, and editing your answer to include explanation as well as the bare fix. Getting the details out of your expert's head and onto the page will widen the search target and provide more help to those who land on the question.

Answer (score -9):

**Answer them if you can, all questions deserve answers.**  What comes around goes around.  Help people if you can.

If it is a simple error on the part of the user that caused the problem then close it.  We use to have the `Too Localized` reason for that, now I have to make a decision every time about what reason to use since none of them really work for that.

Comment: Sorry, but not all questions deserve answers. Some should just be closed, such as the ones that clearly are asking for answers to homework or links to products/services, legal advice, a clear typo ("My query doesn't work. I typed SLECT", and I get an error"), or legal advice like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20917356/62576).

Comment: I'm certainly not talking about spam.

Comment: The key is "if you can".  If someone could answer the question, then it would be great if they did.  __What comes around goes around.__

Comment: Sorry, but no.  The whole reason we have closing is to *prevent new answers from coming in while the question undergoes rehabilitation.* Were that not the case, there would be no incentive for improving question quality.

Comment: I didn't say anything about "spam". :-) What comes around goes around is fine, but SE isn't a karma site. It's a knowledge base, and questions that clearly have no future value should be put on hold or closed until they're clarified; answering them while they're in an intelligible/unmeaningful form removes all incentive to improve them.

Comment: You said "links to products/services", that would be spam.

Comment: No, it isn't. "Where can I find a web hosting service that supports...?" is a common type of question at SO that isn't spam. "Help people if you can" is a great idea when you're discussing giving to charitable organizations, but SO isn't a charity, tutorial site, or link referral service. If you want to help everyone, give to your local homeless shelter or the Red Cross.

Comment: Sorry, but I *hate* your thought "all questions deserve answers". By this you are just trying to make the users of the site more careless. If we answer all questions which don't fit on the site, users will ask such questions again and again without caring of getting closed. Because they are getting response even it is off topic. If we close such questions without answering them, users will think twice before posting such useless and off topic questions.

Comment: @hims056, I guess you probably have never been as desperate as me for an answer.  I can sympathize with their need, even as I wish they did a better job of presenting it.  And that question wasn't off-topic, it just could have been done better.

Comment: Your arguments are losing more and more credence, I'm afraid. Answering unclear, vague, or off-topic questions simply reward people for asking them, and encourage more of the same types of question. "Gee, that question was closed for being off-topic, but I got an answer anyway. I'll ask this one too, and maybe I'll have the same luck." In the meantime, we get the noise, clutter, and wasted time here by users and mods alike, and 100K close review backlog. Thanks. "I'm desperate. It's -10 degrees outside, and I'm worried my pipes might freeze. I know! I'll ask on SO!"

Comment: @KenWhite, I guess you have to have been in someone else's shoes.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: OK. Fair enough. Knock yourself out, starting with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20917931/62576), and **especially** [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20918004/62576) - what do you think he mean? Should she call him for a beer or not? Remember, **all questions deserve answers**.

Comment: @KenWhite, I guessed you missed my phrase that said __"if you can"__ (now repeated for the third time).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Wait... Are you saying that **you can't answer the question** about what a guy meant about waiting until a girl was 18? Surely, that qualifies as a question where "if you can" applies. As I said before, less and less credence.

Comment: Or maybe you just have to stand under the firehose that is a high volume tag on SO @Lance... you think that a lot less questions deserve answers then.

Comment: «All questions deserve answers.» Sure, fine, I can go along with that. But that does _not_ imply that **they should be answered on SO** (or in any other particular place).